# Updated ... need an Ajax example about how client side gets a value from the server side w/o postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

basically I want to check whether a user is logged in with javascript when a button is clicked

I know ajax can do this, but I have no idea where to start... and I do not want to learn the whole ajax

is there any simple code sample I can "borrow"?

==============================UPDATE 2===================================

I posted another question for this one and get the answer below... in case someone has the same question as me...

[Can I return true to asp.net OnClientClick After an Ajax call? Or maybe some other way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578017/can-i-return-true-to-asp-net-onclientclick-after-an-ajax-call-or-maybe-some-oth)

==============================UPDATE=====================================

I read a few examples but I just cannot find the exact one I need. I can get the result from the server side and then... stuck... here is my code and please help with the questions in the comments. Thanks a lot!!!

in .ascx:

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return buttonSubmitOnclick()" OnClick="buttonSubmit_Click" runat="server"/>
```

in .js:

```
function buttonSubmitOnclick() {
  showLogin();
  //What to do here??? how to return true if the ajax call return 'true'?  
  return true;  //???
}


//========== Ajax ==============

function showLogin() {
  var xmlhttp;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        if (xmlhttp.responseText == "false") {
            $find('modalPopupLogin').show();  //Show Login Dialog
        };
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "AjaxService.aspx?t=auth", true);   //??? should the last parameter be "false"???
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Ajax can't do this without some server side code to check the login status. To get you started though, the jQuery Ajax manual has some simple examples that might help: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: yes the server side function will be in asp.net. I want to know the ajax part. do you mean it would be easier with jquery? i thought this should be a simple question and a short ajax call...

Comment: Quoting you... "I do not want to learn the whole ajax"  While I think every programmer has probably shared that sentiment once or twice it would be really beneficial to take a look at how AJAX works/what it is/etc.  Doing "plug n chug" programming has its place but if your dealing w/your apps authentication, it really would behoove you to look deeper than "finding something that works"; that is unless you want to explain to your boss why your website was so easy to hack.

Comment: That being said (apologies for multiline comment); check on the server side save some info in the session when a user is authenticated, use it later when the user pushes the button (anyone can get past js validation with almost no effort at all using something like firefox poster) and while you're writing server side code; use the session to determine if the user is authenticated ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx ).  In other words, in the server side code being executed, it should follow `if(userIsAuthenticated) {performButtonPressedAction()} else { return http403; }`

Comment: @Dave I like your point in your first comment. However sometimes I do not have much time for everything. I have safty consideration, and that s why i choose ajax over a hidden field. I also have basic concepts about how ajax works, but I lack the knowledge about the code details. Thank you for your suggestion anyway!

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straight forward.  Since you are using asp.net probably the easiest way to do this is with a page method.  Page Methods in asp.net allow you to write .NET code in your code behind and then call it using a javascript method.  The page method must be declared static/shared since it will be accessed outside of the page life cycle.

Here are some examples:
 - http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx
 - http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Page Methods are pretty straight forward to call, with or without jQuery.

Comment: I like the first example a lot... just my call is in a control... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is some [good information](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) on using Ajax without jQuery at w3 that has a working example of ajax with asp at the end.  Not too much reading involved.

Updated for question changes:
[At the bottom explains the differences in using asynchronous true vs false](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).

Using async=true, the JS isn't waiting around for the response so you don't want to handle it 'here':

```
function buttonSubmitOnclick() {
  showLogin();
  //What to do here??? how to return true if the ajax call return 'true'?  
  return true;  //???
}
```

Once the xmlhttp.send() is run, js moves on, returns out of showLogin() and will return out of buttomSubmitOnclick, regardless of if the login response has come back yet.

Assuming async true, as you have it, you'll need to expand the conditional in the onreadystatechange function to handle when the responseText == "true".

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    if (xmlhttp.responseText == "false") {
      $find('modalPopupLogin').show();  //Show Login Dialog
    }else if (xmlhttp.responseText == "true") {
      //Continue the previous/submit action here because we are already authenticated
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your update... I still do not knwo how to... "Continue the previous/submit action here because we are already authenticated"? I want it to return true to buttonSubmitOnclick() so the server side will do buttonSubmit_Click... any ideas?

Comment: My attempts were just to weigh in on the use of Ajax in general as I've never worked with asp.  That said, Peter's answer regarding asp's page methods (and profile displayed proficiency in asp) would have me thinking that is the best route to follow.